# Bug with mysql_real_escape_string and addslashes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with `mysql_real_escape_string` and `addslashes`. I have a form in my PHP file where it is `$_POST['title']`, then I have:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['title']));
```

And I insert `$title` into my db. When I want to get this value from my db I have:

```
$title = stripslashes($results['title']);
```

Problem is when I submit something like this: `abs"'@`, my result is: `abs\"\'@`.

I don't know where the bug is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't bother using `addslashes` at all, `mysql_real_escape_string` is more than capable of doing it on its own. So use:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

And remove the `stripslashes` from your retrieval code. If the problem persists, you probably have one of the `magic_quotes` options on - if so, turn it off!

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `addslashes`. You only need `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

Comment: Thank You for response, I try mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use either. The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. Instead, use either [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and prepared statements. Prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to injection and you never have problems with quoting data or forgetting to quote data.

There are other types of injection to consider that escaping and prepared statement parameters don't address. Make sure your production code guards against [cross site scripting](http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html). In the sample, a poster can submit arbitrary HTML in the title element.

Answer (score 1):

The `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` calls and the `magic_quotes` setting were an attempt by early PHP developers to provide guards against SQL injection. However, the state-of-the-art in defensive programming has moved on since then.

There are several problems with this approach, the first of which the escaping algorithm used by each database's dedicated function (e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string()`) are slightly different from what `addslashes()` does.

The other big problem is that escaping data as before it enters processing has proven to be a bad place to do it as now the PHP code has to handle escaped data. This makes the code more complex than necessary because that's not what needs the escaping. Unfortunately, a lot of PHP installations still have `magic_quotes` turned on, which means programmers still need to deal with it.

(If you can't turn off `magic_quotes`, one trick is to do something like this:

```
$stripslashes = (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? "stripslashes" : create_function('$f', 'return $f;'));
```

... near the top of the page and then you can do `$stripslashes($_POST[$form_field])` when you retrieve your variables. The biggest flaw with this is that you have to do it on every page - but sometimes that's the only choice you have. A better alternative is to code up a dispatcher that processes your incoming variables in one place.)

The correct place to escape data is just before it needs escaping. That's why people recommend using `mysql_real_escape_string()` at the point you are assembling SQL. The other advantage to this approach is that when you retrieve the values from the database, you don't have to do anything special to it.

Of course, a properly forward looking solution is to use the mysqli functions instead. This means creating a database connection object with `new mysqli()` and using the instance method `real_escape_string()`.